Bullet points in ASP.NET Core MVC view
I have records in the database that have bullet points in them. When I retrieve the data with bullet points and display them on a Razor page view, it would appear something like this:
 Measures 24”x10”x12” or 2,800 cubic inches of storage space  3 layer laminated polyester waterproof fabric  Commercial grade zipper  Reinforced steel frame closure  Extra heavy duty bottom panel  5 exterior pockets  6 interior pockets  Writable name plate

But I want them to display them like this:
 Measures 24”x10”x12” or 2,800 cubic inches of storage space
 3 layer laminated polyester waterproof fabric
 Commercial grade zipper
 Reinforced steel frame closure
 Extra heavy duty bottom panel
 5 exterior pockets
 6 interior pockets
 Writable name plate

How can I approach this. I'm a little confused on how to tackle this.
Any suggestions?
EDIT
To give more context, the user can copy and paste into a description box like the one I have screenshotted (see below). Once they save the product it appears to me that it goes into a single string as shown below. I know there are 3 records showing but my question still stands. When the user is copying and pasting it shows the correct format but when retrieving it it shows a single string.
What is entered

What is saved in the database

What is retrieved from database


What does the raw string field look like?

Is it coming as single string? Then I would just split in places where this "bullet" occurs. Then I would display them in  as list item . Also you would need to override some CSS styles to remove default browser bullets for unordered lists.

If your goal is to keep the exact same text bullets and just insert line breaks, are you familiar with line breaks in HTML?  Or do you want to turn this into an HTML bulleted list?  Are you familiar with how those are structured?  What have you tried?

The field is a string and it comes out as one string. Also, I haven't tried anything since I don't know how to tackle this

String.split: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-8.0

A simple demo you could follow:
View
@model string
@{
    var bulletPoints = Model?.Split('', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

<ul>
    @foreach (var point in bulletPoints)
    {
        <li>@point.Trim()</li>
    }
</ul>

Controller
public IActionResult Index()
{

    string data = " Measures 24”x10”x12” or 2,800 cubic inches of storage space  3 layer laminated polyester waterproof fabric  Commercial grade zipper  Reinforced steel frame closure  Extra heavy duty bottom panel  5 exterior pockets  6 interior pockets  Writable name plate";
    return View("Index",data);
}

Result

